# Running python code give NameError: name 'ABCMeta' is not defined every time

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

I'm using Python 3.7.3 with PyCharm. When I tried to import `abc` package into my project I got this error followed with `Python quit unexpectedly` alert dialog:

```
Fatal Python error: init_sys_streams: can't initialize sys standard streams
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/io.py", line 52, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/abc.py", line 166, in <module>
NameError: name 'ABCMeta' is not defined
Abort trap: 6
```

---

At first I didn't pay much attention to the error and thought I made a mistake in the code. So I commented `import abc` line. But the error didn't disappear. Moreover, each time I was running `python3` programs I was getting the same error. Even in terminal:

[image: terminal python3 error]

- Previously I had Anaconda installed, but uninstalled it later.
- In my project I'm using `pipenv`
- I also have python 2 but I don't use it. I tried to run it and there was no such error.
- Previously I tried to install `vptyhon` in many ways. I didn't know about `pip` then, so I could mess up the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` file and reinstalling python 3.7.3 resolved the error